# display textbox on clicking the checkbox inside telerik rad grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox, telerik, grid

I have a telerik radgrid where there are checkboxes with values. The values come from database. One of the value is OTHER. When the user checks the OTHER checkbox , a textbox should appear beside the OTHER value inside the grid.

How can I do this using javascript?

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="grid_diag_group" runat="server"                       
                        Width="100%"                     
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
                        <MasterTableView>
                            <Columns>
                                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="TempCol1" HeaderText="Select" ReadOnly="true">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="diag_code" Display="false" Visible="true" AutoPostBackOnFilter="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" />                              
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="diag_desc" UniqueName="diag_description" HeaderText="Diagnosis"
                                    AutoPostBackOnFilter="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            </Columns>
                        </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

my UI is >>

```
[]  MALARIA
[]  T.B.
[]  GLYCOMA
[]  MEASELES
[]  FUNGAL INFECTION
[]  OTHERS
```

When user checks the OTHERS checkbox, textbox should appear beside "OTHERS" inside the grid. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: After OP comment, here is an update that looks for the checkbox values to make textboxes visible. The rest of the comments are still applicable.

```
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="grid_diag_group" runat="server"
                         Width="100%"
                         AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                         HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                         OnNeedDataSource="grid_diag_group_NeedDataSource"
                         OnItemDataBound="grid_diag_group_ItemDataBound">
            <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="diag_code">
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn></telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="TempCol1" HeaderText="Select" ReadOnly="false">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Checked='<%#Eval("diag_code") != null %>' />
                            the desired textbox:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Checked='<%#Eval("diag_code") != null %>' />
                            the desired textbox:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox2" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="diag_code" Display="false" Visible="true" AutoPostBackOnFilter="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="diag_desc" UniqueName="diag_description" HeaderText="Diagnosis"
                                             AutoPostBackOnFilter="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

and the server code:

```
protected void grid_diag_group_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
    {
        GridEditableItem editableItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
        TableCell cell = editableItem["TempCol1"];
        TextBox textBox = editableItem.FindControl("Textbox2") as TextBox;
        CheckBox checkbox = editableItem.FindControl("CheckBox2") as CheckBox;
        if (textBox != null && checkbox.Checked && editableItem.GetDataKeyValue("diag_code").ToString().ToLowerInvariant() == "others")
        {
            textBox.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
        TableCell cell = dataItem["TempCol1"];
        TextBox textBox = dataItem.FindControl("Textbox1") as TextBox;
        CheckBox checkbox = dataItem.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;
        if (textBox != null && checkbox.Checked && dataItem.GetDataKeyValue("diag_code").ToString().ToLowerInvariant() == "others")
        {
            textBox.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

More info on accessing the controls:

- http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/rows/accessing-cells-and-rows#accessing-controls-in-template-column
- http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/rows/accessing-cells-and-rows#accessing-controls-in-editinsert-mode

Here are two issues that make me think you do not actually want that checkbox:

- I do not see the Others column in your grid declaration at all.
- The only place where checkboxes exist, you have set the `ReadOnly` property of the column to `true`.

Here is what I tried to get a simple textbox. Note that this code is very basic and rudimentary and you may want to use your own user controls as edit form if you want to have complex interactions: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/edit-form-types/defaultcs.aspx.

```
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="grid_diag_group" runat="server"
                         Width="100%"
                         AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                         HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                         OnNeedDataSource="grid_diag_group_NeedDataSource">
            <MasterTableView>
                <Columns>
                <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn></telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="TempCol1" HeaderText="Select" ReadOnly="false">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>aaaaaaa
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox2_CheckedChanged" />
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="diag_code" Display="false" Visible="true" AutoPostBackOnFilter="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="diag_desc" UniqueName="diag_description" HeaderText="Diagnosis"
                                             AutoPostBackOnFilter="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

and the server code (quite basic, again)

```
protected void CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Control).Parent.FindControl("Textbox1").Visible=true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am asking to display textbox only for the row where the data is **OTHERS**, i.e. is the last row but not to show the textbox in every other rows. Please suggest how should I do it?

Comment: Edit your question to clarify this..I will post an update to my answer later today when I get to a pc